# How to return the values of functions called with yield in a ContextManager - Python

Tags: python, django

I am trying to organize my code by removing a lot of repetitive logic. I felt like this would be a great use case for a context manager.

When making certain updates in the system, 4 things always happen -

1. We lock the resource to prevent concurrent updates
2. We wrap our logic in a database transaction
3. We validate the data making sure the update is permissible
4. After the function executes we add history rows to the database

I want a wrapper to encapsulate this like below

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def my_manager(resource_id):
    try:
        with lock(resource_id), transaction.atomic():
            validate_data(resource_id)

            resources = yield 

            create_history_objects(resources)
    except LockError:
        raise CustomError

def update(resource_id):
    with my_manager(resource_id):
        _update(resource_id)

def _update(resource_id):
   # do something 
   return resource
```

Everything works as expected except my ability to access resources in the contextmanager, which are `None`. The resources are returned from the function that's called during the `yield` statement.

What is the proper way to access those resources through yield or maybe another utility? Thanks

Comment: There is no `yield` statement. If you change `resources = yield` to `yield resources` and `return _update(resource_id)` within `update` it will work.

Comment: @erip - the yield in the `my_manager` function

Comment: You're not `yield`ing  (or `return`ing) anything in `my_manager` which is why you see `None`.